# failed to push some refs ? #!! merge remote

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have the below and was just wondering what is the best way to deal with this : I edited some files and tried to check-in the new changes . remote  repo has also been updated by someone else.

```
]$ git push
To git@mygitaccount.org:some_project
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'g git@mygitaccount.org...some_project'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes before pushing again.  See the 'Note about
fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

then got this message :

```
Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
as appropriate to mark resolution, or use 'git commit -a'.
```

P.S: I did git pull then git push already , as suggested , but still get the same message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you guessed, you can't push because someone else already pushed, and you have to retrieve their changes first.

The second message is due to the fact that those changes are conflicting with your local ones. To know which files are conflicting, you can run `git status`.

After you resolve every conflicts, you can run, as stated in the message, `git commit -a` to create a merge commit that you'll be able to push.

More generally, you can replace a `pull` by a `fetch` followed with a `merge`. The advantage is that after the `fetch` you can run for example `gitk --all` to easily see what you've just retrieve, hence to decide how you want to handle it.